# How to align icon, number and text in a column?

Tags: html, css, frontend

With the code below I have only been able to put icon, number and the text in the columns with alignment yet to be fixed. I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Could you please show me how to do it by just aligning the first column as seen in the image shown below.

[image]

What I could achieve is as seen below.

[image]

The HTML is:

```
      <div class="row impact-section">  
       <div id="shopify-section-impact" class="shopify-section"><h2>Our Gifts Create an Impact</h2>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         <div><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/160_000_-_People.png?v=1633076419"></div>
         <div>160,000</div>
         <div>Lives impacted last year across 28 states and 35 countries</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/30_-_Diverse.png?v=1633087230"></div>
         <div>30%</div>
         <div>Ratio of PwP's purveyor businesses that are female- and diverse-owned</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/50_000_-_Workforce.png?v=1633087275"></div>
         <div>50,000+</div>
         <div>Hours of training provided for youth and adults with employment barriers</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt2x btn center-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"><a role="button" href=""><button>Learn More About our Impact</button></a></div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Our Gifts Create an Impact

```css
.items{
display:flex;
}
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row impact-section">
    <div id="shopify-section-impact" class="shopify-section"><h2>Our Gifts Create an Impact</h2>
       <div class="items">
           <div class="content col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
               <img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/160_000_-_People.png?v=1633076419">
               <div>
                   <div>160,000</div>
                   <div>Lives impacted last year across 28 states and 35 countries</div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="content col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
               <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/30_-_Diverse.png?v=1633087230">
               <div>
                   <div>30%</div>
                   <div>Ratio of PwP's purveyor businesses that are female- and diverse-owned</div>
               </div>

           </div>
           <div class="content col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

               <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/50_000_-_Workforce.png?v=1633087275">
               <div>
                   <div>50,000+</div>
                   <div>Hours of training provided for youth and adults with employment barriers</div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
        <div class="mt2x btn center-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <a role="button" href=""><button>Learn More About our Impact</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

="content col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/160_000_-_People.png?v=1633076419

160,000
Lives impacted last year across 28 states and 35 countries



[image]

30%
Ratio of PwP's purveyor businesses that are female- and diverse-owned

```
       </div>
       <div class="content col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">

           <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/50_000_-_Workforce.png?v=1633087275">
           <div>
               <div>50,000+</div>
               <div>Hours of training provided for youth and adults with employment barriers</div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
    <div class="mt2x btn center-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
        <a role="button" href=""><button>Learn More About our Impact</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working great except that contents in each column are linear. I need to have 2nd and third values appear one below the other as seen in the origional requirements graphics above. For you to see, I added an image here showing what I want to accomplish. https://pasteboard.co/c62DQSwZ4z1T.png Thank you very much

Comment: I'm following your answer. I still a little more help with aligning them.

Comment: Alignment in your code looks correct, but the code added in the page isn't producing the right results seen with your code.

Comment: Alignment is corrected. I missed something from your code. I need to now give some pace between the icon, number and the text.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer. Could you please set some space between three values in each column?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you trying to achieve. As shown in the image.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  
}


.bold{
  font-weight:900;
  font-size:25px;
}


.button{
  margin-top:20px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row impact-section">  
       <div id="shopify-section-impact" class="shopify-section"><h2>Our Gifts Create an Impact</h2>
         <div class="wrapper">
         <div><img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/160_000_-_People.png?v=1633076419"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         
          <div class="bold">160,000</div>
         <div>Lives impacted last year across 28 states and 35 countries</div>
          
        </div>
  <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/30_-_Diverse.png?v=1633087230"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         
          
         <div class="bold">30%</div>
            <div>Ratio of PwP's purveyor businesses that are female- and diverse-owned</div>
        </div>
<div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0505/7645/7884/files/50_000_-_Workforce.png?v=1633087275"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
         
         <div class="bold">50,000+</div>
          <div>Hours of training provided for youth and adults with employment barriers</div>
        </div>
           </div>
        <div class="mt2x btn center-xs col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 button"><a role="button" href=""><button>Learn More About our Impact</button></a></div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. But, no changes for the button at the bottom.

Comment: @PKTG so you want that learn more button in the same row.

Comment: @PKTG is that ok now?

Comment: No, the button should remain independently in a new row. Also, please note that these contents are dynamically added. I hope you answered with that in the mind.

Comment: @PKTG check again if it is ok then let me know.

Comment: I see only adding `<div class="wrap">` is problem because each column is created with a forloop in PHP. Can you find an alternative? Your answer seems to be a perfect solution.

Comment: I like your answer and will accept it if you can remove this class `<div class="wrap">` and make it still work or make the class accessible to all columns and work. As informed, these columns are generated in a loop so all columns should use the similar classes. I hope you can help fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237720/discussion-between-pktg-and-mr-lazy).

Comment: @PKTG Is that ok now?